# The type javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader cannot be resolved

Tags: android

The type javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.Im getting this error in a line.Which jar am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader` is available on Java SE 6 and higher: not on the Android platform. You must be using a library that depends on that class, but it isn't a standard part of the platform. https://www.findjar.com/class/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html has a list of jar files that may have it, but no guarantees you'll be able to successfully incorporate them.

Comment: Tried 7-8 jar files from the link u gave.They remove the error ,but when i run  it gives me long big story blah blah blah and at the end. Dx 1 error; aborting .Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: Not surprising: the XMLStream classes are Java 6, and Android is Java 5. What you may need to do is obtain the source and build them with a target of 1.5 (so the class file format is an acceptable version).

Comment: Is this link useful? http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/

Comment: That does look like the blueprint. A look over that shows they march through most of the problems you'd run into, so I'd say try that. You will probably need to recompile your dependencies, but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

I came over exactly same topic when trying to get Apache POI running on Android. Also the Apache Poi is using XmlStreamReader. The info described on the docx4java link is a valuable collection of pain points, but in the end it may be a complex task to recompile the full library.

For Apache POI, I found the POI-Android library which already did this job and made POI compatible with android (unfortunately the old POI 3.17, but works fine in my case).

POI-Android: https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android

*Important:* to get POI-Android running, it was important to set the Fasterxml Impls, as described here: https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji/issues/31